# For loop through a specific time interval

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have some problems with a loop. I have two lists, one per emails content and one for dates.

```
my_emails=['my email 1', 'my email 2', 'my email 3']
sent_date=['10/30/2020', '10/29/2020', '10/30/2020']
```

I am trying to run a for loop in order to do the following:

- per each email in my_emails I have information on the date they were sent; So `my email 1` was sent on `10/30/2020`; `my email 2` was sent on  `10/29/2020`, and `my email 3` was sent on `10/30/2020`.
  Per each couple email/date, I would need to look for emails sent 3 days before that date and 3 days after.
  So, for example:

`my email 1` was sent on  `10/30/2020` , then I would need to run some stuff for the next three days (i.e. for  10/31/2020, 11/01/2020, and 11/02/2020) ad for the three days before (i.e. 10/29/2020, 10/28/2020, and 10/27/2020).

I tried to do it as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

for i in my_emails: 
    print(i)
    for t in sent_date:
        t = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y')
        start_date =  t - timedelta(1) # it moves only one day before that date, but actually I should also consider the days after, as in the example
        day = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
        # do some stuff
```

The code does not return the expected range of dates.
Can you please tell me how to include date information per each emails as in the list above, and how to run some code within the date range?

Thanks

My expected output would be:

- my email 1 : run some code from date 10/27/2020 to 11/02/2020
- my email 2 : run some code from date 10/26/2020 to 11/01/2020
- my email 3 : run some code from date 10/27/2020 to 11/02/2020

since the date may change, I cannot consider a unique range for them, but considering the corresponding date in the list sent_date as starting point to calculate 3 days before and 3 days after that date.

Comment: Three days prior is `t - timedelta(days=3)`, and three days after is `t + timedelta(days=3)`.

Comment: Hi John, yes you are right. I copied the code that I was updating (since it was not working, I tested it only for one day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_range = 3
for m,t in zip(my_emails, sent_date):
    t = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y')
    before_dates = [ t - timedelata(i) for i in range(1,date_range+1)]
    after_dates = [ t  + timedelata(i) for i in range(1,date_range+1)]
    #do stuff with mail(m) and dates
```

Comment: thanks a lot Rajith. One question on your code: since I need to extract emails within the same day, before going through the next days and the previous days in the range I selected, how should I edit your code? in mine I was setting the condition putting `for t in sent_date:  start_date=t end_date=t` , i.e. the same date, then I should have moved to the next/previous day. Another approach would be calculating first the range that I need to consider for each date, starting from the more recent date and going back through time.